# Python function to ping LAN is not storing results in global list

Tags: python

I am trying to write a small script to basically have some functionality like nmap (very simple script) and I am making progress, but am stuck on a silly part of it.

I think this could be a good learning moment for me in python.

The script successfully pings the entire subnet and prints out information on which hosts were responsive. The next step for me is to store those IPs into a list for later processing. This is where I am stuck: live_hosts always returns empty. Printing the list within the function does show the current alive IP but is overwritten on each new call, and then entirely empty after the map() function completes.

```
import subprocess
import multiprocessing
import ipaddress
# import platform
import socket


#Getting information about network
def get_ip():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        # doesn't even have to be reachable
        s.connect(('10.255.255.255', 1))
        IP = s.getsockname()[0]    
    except Exception:
        IP = '127.0.0.1'
    finally:
        s.close()
    return IP

host = get_ip()
octets = host.split(".")
subnet = ''

for octet in octets:
    if octet == octets[-1]:
        subnet = subnet[:-1] + "."
        break
    else:
        subnet = subnet + octet + "."

#pinging hosts on network to check for life

ips = (subnet+'%d' % i for i in range(1, 255))
**live_hosts = []**

def ping(ip,live_hosts=live_hosts):

    ping = subprocess.call(["ping", "-W", "1", "-c", "1", ip],
    stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL
    )
    
    if ping == 0:
        print(ip +" is up!")
        live_hosts.append(ip)
        return live_hosts

with multiprocessing.Pool(200) as p:
    p.map(ping,ips)  
    **print(live_hosts)**
```

I have tried including live_hosts as a global variable, creating a temporary list and pointing it to live_hosts, but no luck.

I don't know what I am missing and would really appreciate some suggestions! Thanks. I know I can be more pythonic too, so any pythonic suggestions are welcome too!

Comment: It seems like you're not saving the return value anywhere, no? As an aside, a `multiprocessing.Pool` with 200 processes seems excessive, does that not cause any performance issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the global `live_hosts` list is accessed from each worker by `p.map(ping,ips)`, it is copied into that worker's scope.  When a worker first comes up, that list will be empty.

Each call within a worker then does its `append()` operation on its own copy and returns the current value of its copy of `live_hosts`.

Your call to `map()` does not capture the return values.

The right way to do this is to not have a global `live_hosts` list, not have a `live_hosts` in `ping()`, and have `ping()` return just the `ip` if the host was reachable.

Then capture that with `live_hosts = p.map(ping, ips)`.

I think it will be filled with a lot of nulls, so use a list comprehension to filter those out:

`live_hosts = [x for x in p.map(ping,ips) if x != None]`

Regarding performance, the calls to `ping()` that will take the longest are the ones that do nothing but sit there and wait the one second (`-W 1`) for pinging a non-existent host to time out.

Since your targets code is hard-coded to assume a /24 (Class-C) and tries to ping every host in that assumed subnet, you may as well either increase your poolsize to 254 or decrease it to 127.

Unless you have a well-populated subnet, your overall script will probably be waiting for two timeouts before the `map()` operation completes.

I would increase the poolsize to 254 and change the call to ping to use `-W 2` or even higher to get a better survey of your network.

Comment: My assumption was that the error was in the map function and how it was handling the returns. Thank you for elaborating on what was actually happening within the workers' scope. I applied the list comprehension to filter out nulls and everything came together! 

The randomly large pool size, was just to see if the time to completion would be noticeably different and accidentally left it in for the post. I really appreciate the extra logic regarding how to determine the appropriate pool size for a script with this purpose and context.

Thank you for the perfect answer/solution and insights!